# Rational solutions of $x^4(k^2+4)-4kx^2=z^2$, where $k>0$ is given rational.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametrization

How to generate some parametric family of rational solutions to $x^4(k^2+4)-4kx^2=z^2$, where $k>0$ is given rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=4$, Above equation is shown below:

$20x^4=(4x)^2+z^2$  ------(A)

Equation $(A)$ has parametric solution:

$x=2p(5m^2-4m+1)$

$z=16(p^2)(25m^4-45m^3+30m^2-9m+1)$

Where, $p=[1/(5m^2-1)]$

For $m=3$ we have:

$(x,z,k)=[(17/11),(1054/121),(4)]$

Comment: @ Sam, How did you arrived at that parametric solution?

Comment: Equation (A) is equivalent to (5x^2-4)=[(z)/(2x)]^2=(y)^2

Comment: Since (x,z)=(2,16) is numerical solution of equation (A), it implies (y) =(4). Hence parametrize (5x^2-4)=y^2 at (x,y) =(2,4). After arriving at parameter's of (x,y) we use the equality (z)=( 2xy) to find (z)

Comment: Good Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be written
\begin{equation*}
x^2((k^2+4)x^2-4k)=z^2
\end{equation*}
and, so we need 
\begin{equation*}
(k^2+4)x^2-4k=y^2
\end{equation*}

If $x=1$, then $y=\pm (k-2)$, so the line $y=k-2+m(x-1)$ will meet the quadric at the further point
\begin{equation*}
x=\frac{-(k^2-2km+m^2+4m+4)}{k^2-m^2+4}
\end{equation*}

For example, if $k=1/2$, putting $m=4$ gives
\begin{equation*}
z^2=\frac{3^2*5^2*43^2*103^2}{2^2*47^4}
\end{equation*}

Allan Macleod